# Get last values from joined table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, home-automation

For a Home-Automation Dashboard I am trying to display the latest values for different devices in different rooms.
My tables look like this
Table: devices

| DeviceID | Floor | Room | Measurement | More Information |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | WC | Room-Temp | ... |
| 2 | 0 | WC | Desired Room-Temp | ... |
| 3 | 0 | WC | rel. Humidity | ... |
| ... | .... | ... | .... | ... |
| 15 | 1 | Kid | Room-Temp | ... |
| 16 | 1 | Kid | Desired Room-Temp | ... |
| 17 | 1 | Kid | rel. Humidity | ... |

Apart from that I have a table "messdaten" (=measurements) where I store the collected data (DeviceID+Timestamp is unique).

| DeviceID | Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | 2022-07-28 13:00:03 | 63 |
| 15 | 2022-07-28 12:58:37 | 21.3 |
| 17 | 2022-07-28 12:58:37 | 60 |
| 1 | 2022-07-28 12:55:00 | 20.8 |
| ... | ... | ... |

What I would like to have now is a table in this form where I find all the latest data from each device for one specific room (here for example "WC").

| DeviceID | Floor | Room | Measurement | Timestamp | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | WC | Room-Temp | 2022-07-28 12:55:00 | 20.8 |
| 2 | 0 | WC | Desired Room-Temp | 2022-07-28 12:53:00 | 20.5 |
| 3 | 0 | WC | rel. Humidity | 2022-07-28 13:00:03 | 63 |

My closest approach so far is:

```
SELECT devices.DeviceID, Floor, Room, Measurement, max(messdaten.Timestamp), messdaten.Value 
FROM devices LEFT JOIN messdaten ON messdaten.DeviceID = devices.DeviceID 
WHERE   Room = (SELECT Room FROM devices WHERE DeviceID = 1) 
GROUP BY devices.DeviceID 
ORDER BY `devices`.`Measurement` ASC;
```

Unfortunately using "max" in Timestamp only applies on the column 'Timestamp' so that I get the latest timestamp but not the corresponding value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER()` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT d.DeviceID, d.Floor, d.Room, d.Measurement, m.Timestamp, m.Value,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY d.DeviceID ORDER BY m.Timestamp DESC) rn
    FROM devices d
    LEFT JOIN messdaten m ON m.DeviceID = d.DeviceID 
    WHERE Room IN (SELECT Room FROM devices WHERE DeviceID = 1) 
)

SELECT DeviceID, Floor, Room, Measurement, Timestamp, Value
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY Measurement;
```